# What can I find in the Sedalia police station?

Tags: the-walking-dead-survival-instinct

In Walking Dead - Survival Instinct, you have the option of taking on a side quest at the second level (or the town named Sedalia), which involves finding some batteries in the police station. You don't *have* to take the quest to complete the level, but I've read that there are a lot of interesting and useful things you can pick up rummaging through it.

The problem is, that place is *packed* full of walkers, and getting through every room in the station with enough life to actually proceed to clear the final level is turning out to be extremely hard. I'm getting pretty tired of the level and I'm thinking about just ditching the side quest to complete the main level, but I'm wondering what else might be in that place that I'll wish I'd stuck around to find.

So far, I've found:

- A bolt action rifle and a small amount of ammunition
- A revolver, with a small amount of ammunition

Is there anything else to be found in this place (besides the batteries, of course)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is another survivor in one of the cells, who will trade food for 10 revolver and 10 rifle ammo. You can find the food in the building where Jimmy Blake (the guy you need the batteries for) is on the roof. But depending on your playstyle, you might not need the ammo anyway.

But keep in mind that Jimmy Blake won't come with you as a survivor if you don't give him the batteries. But if I remember correctly, there isn't enough space in the car for everyone anyway. So, if you are happy with the amount of ammo you can just leave the side quest. You'll just miss some irrelevant dialogue and Jimmy as a survivor.

Answer (score 0):

I have beat the game countless times and i even got the unlimited ammo relic in doing so and in my experience beating the game so many times i have found that in sedalia if you manage to find  the officer who gives ammo for food and the batteries requested from jimky blake you will get ammo and coverage 2 things that you will definitely need in that part of the game. Good luck and good hunting the walkers!